# git upload-pack: protocol error, expected to get sha

Tags: git

On the server (site@site)

```
> git init --bare
```

Back on my client

```
> git remote add origin site@site:/home/git/repos/repo_name/

> git push origin master 

Counting objects: 43, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
fatal: git upload-pack: protocol error, expected to get sha, not '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 f9b6ddffc38fe0cfcd0ab311197bb31d1fab4856 refs/heads/master'
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'site@site:/home/git/repos/repo_name/'
```

Not sure what's causing this error on initial repo push. I tried creating a simple repository with just a text file, and that worked. I suspect perhaps there's a file causing the error but am not sure how to trace down which file it is (apart from removing everything from the repo and adding them back in one at a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pushing a new repo on an empty repo usually requires -u

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: which version of git on server and client?

Comment: on client 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)

Comment: on server git version 1.8.1 GIT

Comment: I also get the same/very similar error on my windows box as a client (git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0):

    fatal: git upload-pack: protocol error, expected to get sha, not '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 f9b6ddffc38fe0cfcd0ab311197bb31d1fab4856 refs/heads/master'
    Counting objects: 43, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
    fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
   error: failed to push some refs to 'site@site:/home/git/repos/repo_name/'

Comment: I tried a similar setup (1.8.1.2 on mac, 1.7.2.5 on linux as server) and things worked.  Maybe reinit the repo on the remote?  what protocol are you using?  ssh?

Comment: ssh yes, i've tried reiniting the repo on remote. might be something to do with that it's on a vps and i had to compile git myself with these options?

make NO_CURL=1 NO_MSGFMT=YesPlease NO_TCLTK=YesPlease NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease prefix=/usr/local install

Comment: I actually tried the other way around, 1.8 was on client (mac).  There is a 1.8.1.2 on http://git-scm.com/, maybe worth a shot?  And does your remote uses ssh://site@site:...

Comment: Thanks! installing 1.8.1.2 on the server fixed my problem.